# Missing 'utf' module

Tags: python, python-3.x, site-packages

I am trying to install and use this Gmail library https://github.com/charlierguo/gmail I can successfully download and install the package using python3 setup.py install. However, when I go to import the module I receive the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "process.py", line 1, in <module>
import gmail
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gmail-0.0.5-py3.6.egg/gmail/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gmail-0.0.5-py3.6.egg/gmail/gmail.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utf'
```

I inspect the site-packages folder and utf.py is there. I have reinstalled, changed names, and replaced this utf file, but it seems to be overlooked every time.

Comment: This generally suggests that you the installation isn't in the proper library.  By any chance, do you have Python 2 installed as well?  Did you use an installation command specific to Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the library (or it doesn't support Python 3). This line:

```
from utf import encode as encode_utf7, decode as decode_utf7
```

won't work on Python 3 because relative imports need to be spelled like `.utf`, so it should be:

```
from .utf import encode as encode_utf7, decode as decode_utf7
```

Looking into it more, it looks like it only supports Python 2, given that it uses `unicode`, which doesn't exist in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you. That solved that issue, but brought me to a new one. When I try `from gmail import Gmail` I receive an import error.